# Enabling paytm payment gateway on kitsune websites

Tags: web, serverless, paytm

I am trying to enable Paytm as my payment gateway in the ecommerce website I am creating using `kitsune`.

When I enable the Paytm component in the IDE, I can see the following in my kitsune-settings.json file (the preview section)

```
"preview": [
  {
    "domain": "example.com",
    "gateway": "paytm",
    "api_secret": "API_SECRET",
    "api_key": "API_KEY",
    "redirect_path": "/transaction_status",
    "api_url": "https://pguat.paytm.com",
    "payment_request_endpoint": "/oltp-web/processTransaction",
    "transaction_status_endpoint": "/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?JsonData="
  }
]
```

Where do I find the right values for API_SECRET and API_KEY ?

Comment: have u referred this link https://developer.paytm.com/docs

Comment: does not talk about how to use the PG with kitsune serverless websites

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://business.paytm.com/ and Login with your Paytm account
2. Once you login, navigate to API Keys under the Developers section
3. You can see two values under the "Test API Details" which you need to use.
4. Use "Test Merchant ID" value as the API_SECRET in your preview section of kitsune-settings.json
5. Use "Test Account Secret Key" value as the API_KEY in your preview section of kitsune-settings.json

That's all. Now you can build the kitsune project and test your Paytm integrated payment with following code

```
<a k-pay-amount="2000" k-pay-description="Testing Paytm">Pay using Paytm</a>
```